# WordPress код подгрузки custom post

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Есть такой код:

js:

```js
$('#load_more_posts').on('click', function(e){
        console.log('hi');
        e.preventDefault();
         var $offset = $(this).data('offset');
         console.log('var'+$offset);
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                offset: $offset,
                action: 'load_more_posts'
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                $('#load_more_posts').data('offset', parseInt(response.data.offset));
               

            }
        }); 
    });
```

php:

```html
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'load_more_posts' );
function load_more_posts(){
    
  global $post;
    $rst=[];
    $country_id=get_the_id();
    $query = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type'     => 'hotel',
            'posts_per_page'=> 2,
            'offset'=> $_POST['offset'],
            'meta_query'     => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'acf_hotel_country', // name of custom field
                    'value' => $country_id, // matches exactly "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ));

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
             $rst[] = $post;
           
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $offset = $_POST['offset']+2;
        
        
    endif;
   wp_send_json_success(array('post'=>$rst, 'offset'=>$offset));
}
```

Он возвращает данные поста в консоль. 
Как вывести на фронтэнд готовый div? Когда я дописываю что-то к $rst[] = $post  выходит ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined"

Comment: "Дописываю что-то" - что? Куда? зачем? Вопрос из серии - я где-то нагуглил код, сам ничего не понимаю, сделайте все за меня.

Comment: Вопрос думаю понятен,попрошу не умничать

Comment: Вопрос непонятен ни разу. Был бы понятен - я бы ответил. Пока что задал уточняющие вопросы - что и куда дописываете и с какой целью.